# Java RegEx to remove English words but exclude some words

Tags: java, regex, text, replaceall

I try to use this RegEx `(?![link]|[hashTag]|[lough])([A-Za-z0-9]+)` 
to replace every english word in text with `[englishWord]` but keep these tags [link], [hashTag] and [lough].
using the following line:

```
 x = x.replaceAll("(?![link]|[hashTag]|[lough])([A-Za-z0-9]+)", "[englishWord]");
```

An input example:

```
 BBC  The Other [lough] The kough there are [link] [hashTag]
```

The resulted output;

```
 [englishWord] Th[englishWord] [englishWord] [lough] Th[englishWord] kough [englishWord] a[englishWord] [link] [hashTag]
```

while i want the output become as:

```
[englishWord] [englishWord] [englishWord] [lough] [englishWord] [englishWord] [englishWord] [englishWord] [link] [hashTag]
```

Can any one please tell me where is the problem ?

Comment: Do you want to remove all words but keep `[lough]`, `[link]` and `[hashTag]`? Your code does not match the example. Note to match `[` you need to escape it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes, why some litters not removed ?

Comment: Then try [`.replaceAll("(\\[(?:link|hashTag|lough)])|\\s*[A-Za-z0-9]+", "$1").trim()`](http://ideone.com/nAkJn0).

Comment: but i need to replace english words with [englishWord] @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Your regex is equal to `(?![linkhasTgou])[A-Za-z0-9]+` - only matches 1+ ASCII alphanumeric symbols but not starting with those inside a character class.

Comment: If you need to replace with `[englishWord]`, why did you write *"while i want the output become as: `[lough] [link] [hashTag]`"*?

Comment: A waste of time this question.

Comment: Try [this approach](http://ideone.com/bBFsXc) that outputs `[englishWord]  [englishWord] [englishWord] [lough] [englishWord] [englishWord] [englishWord] [englishWord] [link] [hashTag]`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Make that an answer, at least you get something from this...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew sorry i miss that, i made an edit on output

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew many of thanks, the problem is fixed :)

Comment: @Amani: Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)) since you reached 15 rep points and obtained the upvoting privilege.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is equal to [`(?![linkhasTgou])[A-Za-z0-9]+`](https://regex101.com/r/NE8rvm/1) and it only matches 1+ ASCII alphanumeric symbols but not starting with those inside the negated character class

I suggest using a regex that will match and capture these 3 "entities" into Group 1 and use `\p{Alnum}+` alternative to just match any alphanumeric char sequence. Then use `Matcher#appendReplacement()` to check if Group 1 matched, and if it did, reinsert the value back into the result, else, replace with the hardcoded string:

```
String s = "BBC  The Other [lough] The kough there are [link] [hashTag]";
String p = "(\\[(?:link|hashTag|lough)])|\\p{Alnum}+";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(p).matcher(s);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
    if (m.group(1) != null)
        m.appendReplacement(sb, m.group(1));
    else
        m.appendReplacement(sb, "[englishWord]");
}
m.appendTail(sb); 
System.out.println(sb);
```

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/bBFsXc)

Note that the `[` outside a character class must be escaped if you need to match a literal `[` symbol.

**Pattern details**:

- `(\\[(?:link|hashTag|lough)])` - Capturing group 1 matching:

  - `\\[` - a literal `[`
  - `(?:link|hashTag|lough)` - either `link` or (`|`) `hashTag` or `lough`
  - `]` - a literal `]`
- `|`  - or
- `\\p{Alnum}+` - 1+ alphanumeric chars.